# Exchange 2010 Server not receiving "reply" emails from 2 domains

Tags: exchange, email-server

This is a strange issue, and I'm not sure it's even on our side.  But trying to get to the bottom of it.

We have an in-house Exchange 2010 server. A month ago, this one domain - let's call it ccc.com - started having trouble just with replies to our company's domain.  New emails came through fine.  Replies were lost in space. No bounceback.

I checked the Protocol logs and there is no record of our server rejecting replies, or even receiving it.  I see the new emails in the logs and they come through fine.

Makes me think the problem is on senders side, however, just last week a complete different domain - call it sss.com - started having the same trouble.  No bounceback as far as we know.

I'm stumped and can't figure out how I can troubleshoot this further, but seems like it's a problem on our side.

Thanks in advance for any troubleshooting steps I might take.

Comment: Do you have any spam filter that inbound messages hit before being delivered to your Exchange box?

Comment: Good question, but no, the MX record is set to deliver directly to the Exchange server (through a Sonicwall firewall).

Comment: I did see that I dont' have a valid Reverse DNS record, so I've requested the ISP to add it.  Wondering if that will fix it...

Comment: That's a good thing to have regardless.  Interesting problem, no other ideas for you, sorry.

Comment: Might be interesting to check mx records for ccc.com and sss.com; could they be using the same mail service?  Certainly doesn't explain why new messages come through and only replies don't, but could be interesting to check regardless.

Comment: hmm that would be interesting if that was the case, i will check and post. thanks!

Comment: 916 Networks - This is very odd, I'm wondering, when you send a customer an email if you have a different "Reply-To" header then your "From" email. If your "Reply-To" contains "+" addressing or other not normal characters, the sending mail server can have issues replying to it. If you don't know if your email has a "Reply-To" header, just send in email to `mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com` it will send you back a report with most of your header fields on top - See if the "Reply-To" seems strange to you.

Comment: Thanks Henry, that's a great idea. I'll try that now and post the results here.